# How to trim the file extension and save it to another variable in bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here's the mlexe.bat:

```
ML /Zi /c /Fl /coff %1.asm
LINK /subsystem:console %1.obj
```

It can be used this way:

```
mlexe hello
```

But I want it to work this way:

```
mlexe hello.asm
```

How to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [using batch parameters](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true), you need `%~n1`.